# Torsion-free subgroup of affine group

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group and $\varphi:G\to \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb C)$ a homomorphism, where $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb C)$ is the group of complex affine transfromations $a z+b$.

Can we find a torsion free-subgroup $H$ of $G$ with finite index? And can we find a normal subgroup $H$ which is torsion-free with finite index?

Comment: You probably want $\varphi$ to be injective.

Comment: What do you mean by $Aut(\mathbb{C})$, automorphisms preserving which structure?

Comment: @Antoine Labelle: From the title it seems safe to assume that it is the group of affine transformations $z\mapsto az+b$.

Comment: Having a finite-index torsion-free subgroup and a finite-index torsion-free normal subgroup are equivalent conditions.

Comment: Please to include the definition of "Aut(C)", and also assume that the homomorphism is injective.

Comment: Then such an $H$ exsits if $\varphi$ is injective ? And what happens when $\varphi$ is not injective?

Comment: If $\varphi(G)={1}$, your group is an arbitrary finitely generated group.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. More generally, for any field $K$ we have an embedding of $\operatorname{Aff}(K^n)$ in $\operatorname{GL}_{n+1}(K)$, and so if $K$ has characteristic zero we can apply Selberg's lemma to conclude that a finitely generated group of affine transformations of $K^n$ is virtually torsion-free. The normal core of any finite index torsion-free subgroup will be a normal finite index torsion-free subgroup.

Comment: Of course in such a case the projection of $G$ in $K^*$ if a f.g. abelian group, so is virtually torsion-free, and hence so is $G$ (since the kernel $K$ is torsion-free), so the fact is straightforward without use of the (non-trivial) Selberg lemma.

Comment: Yes, the case $n=1$ is easier, but in general you need Selberg.

Comment: Yes of course for the affine group in every dimension it's equivalent to Selberg.